# Foreach invalid argument

Tags: php, foreach, mysqli

I am creating a search function that will allow a user to search for a house in my database by postcode initially. The function can be seen below, when the function is executed and finds a true statement I get no errors however when I execute the search and I get a no fields been returned I am left with this error:

```
   No Records Found
   Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/undergradpad/search.php on line 26
```

I want it to display No Records Found however I don't know how I should correct the above error.

search.php:

```
<table width="500" border="1" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
<th width="16" scope="row">id</th>
<td width="95">bedrooms</td>
<td width="140">description</td>
<td width="104">roadname</td>
 <td width="71">postcode</td>
</tr>


<?php
    require("classes/class.House.inc");

    $obj = new House();
    $obj->search($_POST['term']);
    foreach($obj->data as $val){
    extract($val);
?>

<tr>
<td scope="row"><?php echo $id; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $bedrooms; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $description; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $roadname; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $postcode; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

classes/class.House.inc:

```
 <?php 
 include("connect/class.Database.inc");

 class House extends Database {


    public function read(){

            $query = "SELECT * FROM houses";

            $result = $this->mysqli->query($query);

            $num_result = $result->num_rows;    
            if($num_result > 0){
                while($rows =$result->fetch_assoc()){               
                    $this->data[]=$rows;
                    //print_r($rows);
                }           
                return $this->data;
            }
    }

    public function search ($term){

                    $query = "SELECT * FROM houses WHERE postcode like '%".$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($term)."%'";
                    $result = $this->mysqli->query($query);


                    $num_result = $result->num_rows;

                    if($num_result > 0){
                        while($rows =$result->fetch_assoc()){               
                            $this->data[]=$rows;
                            //print_r($rows);
                        }           
                        return $this->data;
                    } else{
                     echo 'No Records Found';    
                        }
    }
 }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$obj` is a `House` object. It has no `$data` property, even if you use it. The `search` method sets this property, but only if records are found. If no records are found, the method echoes a value.

I would change it like this: Instead of echoing an error, make the method return false:

```
public function search ($term){

    $query = "SELECT * FROM houses WHERE postcode like '%".$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($term)."%'";
    $result = $this->mysqli->query($query);

    $data = false;

    $num_result = $result->num_rows;

    while($row =$result->fetch_assoc()){               
        $data[]=$row;
    }           
    return $data;
}
```

Now, the function return an array of false if there is no data. You can now use it like this:

```
$obj = new House();
if ($data = $obj->search($_POST['term']))
{
  foreach($obj->data as $val){
    extract($val);
  }
}
```

The changes I made:
- No longer set `data` as a property, since you also return it. You can still do that, if you like, but I think it's confusing to do both.
- Return false if there's no data.
- Change the variable `rows` to `row`, since it only contains one row.

Comment: thank you for the answer I tried your method however, using your function above returned the true query with an error. However I kept your if statement as this actually helped to solve the error. So I thank you!

Answer (score 1):

in this variable ($obj->data) you just get null data.

First check if not empty and than use foreach and don't have error if yout method don't return null data

just check if (!empty($obj->data)
{
foreach code
}

Answer (score 0):

```
if(is_array($obj->data)){
foreach code
}
else{
no record
}
```